# Unknown error while running app Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When I deploy the file .war to the Glassfish 4.1.1 server the error in the log below appears. I can not know where the problem is.

```loggers
 [2017-07-31T18:45:14.840-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.admingui] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1501541114840] [levelValue: 800] [[
 Exception Occurred :Error occurred during deployment: null. Please see server.log for more details.]]

 [2017-07-31T18:45:14.840-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1501541114840] [levelValue: 1000] [[
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred during deployment: null. Please see server.log for more details.
 at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.RestUtil.parseResponse(RestUtil.java:506)
 at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.RestUtil.restRequest(RestUtil.java:237)
 at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.RestUtil.restRequest(RestUtil.java:164)
 at org.glassfish.admingui.common.handlers.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:198)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler.Handler.invoke(Handler.java:442)
 at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:420)
 at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:394)
 at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.invokeCommandHandlers(CommandActionListener.java:150)
 at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.processAction(CommandActionListener.java:98)
 at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
 at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
 at com.sun.webui.jsf.component.WebuiCommand.broadcast(WebuiCommand.java:166)
 at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
 at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
 at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:223)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:678)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred during deployment: null. Please see server.log for more details.
 at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.RestUtil.parseResponse(RestUtil.java:461)
 ... 69 more]]
```

I need help solving this problem. If I need to, I'll send more details about the project Spring MVC.
The server is located on a physical PC on my local network. I add all publishing rights in Glassfish folder, but the error continues.

Comment: share the server.log as well.

Comment: You may notice that line 12716 appears in `Deployment_Success`, but then the error appears. Link to [server.log](https://github.com/nsbrno/ProjetoWebSpringBasico/blob/SisInfoWeb/src/main/resources/server.log)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the problem.
I have an XML with name `glassfish-resources.xml` inside `WEB-INF` folder. Inside the `glassfish-resources.xml` it has a `jdbc-connection-pool` and the problem was the name of that `jdbc-connection-pool` that contained the slash. When I removed the bar () the problem solved at the same time.
Below is the code before and after.

**Code before.**

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
 <resources>
     <jdbc-connection-pool 
     allow-non-component-callers="false" 
     associate-with-thread="false" 
     connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" 
     connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" 
     connection-leak-reclaim="false" 
     connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" 
     connection-validation-method="auto-commit" 
     datasource-classname="org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver" 
     fail-all-connections="false" 
     idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" 
     is-connection-validation-required="false" 
     is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" 
     lazy-connection-association="false" 
     lazy-connection-enlistment="false" 
     match-connections="false" 
     max-connection-usage-count="0" 
     max-pool-size="32" 
     max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" 
     name="jdbc_firebirdsql_172_16_0_251_3050_C_\SisInfo\delphi\SINOVO_FIR_C_SYSDBAPool" 
     non-transactional-connections="false" 
     pool-resize-quantity="2" 
     res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
     statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" 
     steady-pool-size="8" 
     validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" 
     wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
         <property name="serverName" value="172.16.0.251"/>
         <property name="portNumber" value="3050"/>
         <property name="databaseName" value="C"/>
         <property name="User" value="SYSDBA"/>
         <property name="Password" value="1"/>
         <property name="URL" value="jdbc:firebirdsql://172.16.0.251:3050/C:\SisInfo\delphi\SINOVO.FIR"/>
         <property name="driverClass" value="org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver"/>
     </jdbc-connection-pool>
     <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="java:app/SI" object-type="user" pool-name="jdbc_firebirdsql_172_16_0_251_3050_C_\SisInfo\delphi\SINOVO_FIR_C_SYSDBAPool"/>
 </resources>
```

**Code after**

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
 <resources>
     <jdbc-connection-pool 
     allow-non-component-callers="false" 
     associate-with-thread="false" 
     connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" 
     connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" 
     connection-leak-reclaim="false" 
     connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" 
     connection-validation-method="auto-commit" 
     datasource-classname="org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver" 
     fail-all-connections="false" 
     idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" 
     is-connection-validation-required="false" 
     is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" 
     lazy-connection-association="false" 
     lazy-connection-enlistment="false" 
     match-connections="false" 
     max-connection-usage-count="0" 
     max-pool-size="32" 
     max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" 
     name="jdbc_firebirdsql_172_16_0_251_3050" 
     non-transactional-connections="false" 
     pool-resize-quantity="2" 
     res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
     statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" 
     steady-pool-size="8" 
     validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" 
     wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
         <property name="serverName" value="172.16.0.251"/>
         <property name="portNumber" value="3050"/>
         <property name="databaseName" value="C"/>
         <property name="User" value="SYSDBA"/>
         <property name="Password" value="1"/>
         <property name="URL" value="jdbc:firebirdsql://172.16.0.251:3050/C:\SisInfo\delphi\SINOVO.FIR"/>
         <property name="driverClass" value="org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver"/>
     </jdbc-connection-pool>
     <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="java:app/SI" object-type="user" pool-name="jdbc_firebirdsql_172_16_0_251_3050"/>
 </resources>
```